# pointers in structs a memory leak?

Tags: memory, pointers, memory-leaks

I couldn't find any mention of this online... wouldn't putting a pointer in a struct be a bad thing? (at least in the modern object oriented programing) The programmer would inevitably creating a memory leak correct? (unless they, every time they use it, they disassociate the memory every time)

Assuming that the above is correct... is it considered a bad practice to use pointers in structs? - specifically accounting potential memory leaks?

Comment: What language are we talking about? C? C++?

Comment: This is what constructors and destructors are all about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is about C++, putting a dumb pointer into a `struct` is indeed dangerous if this pointer refers to an object (or an array of objects) that is owned by the `struct`'s instance (that is, the instance is responsible for the proper deletion of the object).

Copying an instance of the `struct` means copying all of its members. After that, you end up with several instances of that `struct` having pointers to the same object. When all of these instances are about to be deleted, you would have to delete the object referred to by the pointer. However, if one of them is about to be deleted, it is often hard to tell if other instances are still around somewhere.

A way out of this would be reference-counting, done by clever implementing constructors, destructors, and assignment. Fortunately you don't need to implement this yourself, since it's already been done in so-called smart pointer. Either your standard library ships TR1's `std::tr1::shared_ptr` or it already comes with C++11's `std::shared_ptr` or you can download the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org) and use their [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).